# Flask необязательный аргумент для url

Tags: python, flask

Пытаюсь сделать так, что бы по ендпоинту можно было как передать аргументы так и просто вызвать всю инфу.

Сейчас реализовано так

```
class Books(flask_restful.Resource):

    def __init__(self):
        self.reqparse = reqparse.RequestParser()
        self.reqparse.add_argument('categoty_id', type=int, location='json')
        super(Books, self).__init__()

    def get(self, categoty_id):
        # some logic
        return None


app = Flask('test')
app.config["DEBUG"] = True
api = flask_restful.Api(app)
api.add_resource(Books, '/api/v1/books', '/api/v1/books/<categoty_id>')
app.run()
```

Получаю конкретную категорию книг (допустим categoty_id=123 , научная литература)

```
http://localhost/api/v1/books/123
```

И хочу что бы было доступно вернуть все книги по url

```
http://localhost/api/v1/books
```

Пытался добавить required=False при добавлении аргумента. Однако это не решило проблему.

```
self.reqparse.add_argument('category_id', type=int, location='json', required=False)
```

Подскажите, как сделать, что бы одновременно по эндпоинту можно было забрать и категорию книг и все.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

При обращении по адресу `/api/v1/books` показывает ошибку: `TypeError: get() missing 1 required positional argument: 'category_id'`. Это означает что метод вызывается без параметра, хотя он требуется.

Просто добавьте параметру id значение по-умолчанию:

```
class Books(flask_restful.Resource):

    def __init__(self):
        self.reqparse = reqparse.RequestParser()
        self.reqparse.add_argument('category_id', type=int, location='json')
        super(Books, self).__init__()

    def get(self, category_id='default'):
        return category_id
```

При запросе на `/api/v1/books` будет возвращать "default", при запросе на `/api/v1/books/123` - "123".

Именно строку `"default"` указал для примера, можно использовать просто `None`:

```
def get(self, category_id=None):
    if category_id is None:
        ...  # Вернуть список всех книг
    else:
        ...  # Вернуть книгу с указанным id категории
```

Comment: У меня реализована ещё pagination и получется что когда я запрашиваю 1 елемент , то ошибка. Так работает http://localhost/api/v1/books?start=1&limit=20 , а http://localhost/api/v1/books/123/?start=1&limit=20 нет

Comment: @WilteRatenau как я понимаю, при указании id вы хотите получать конкретную книгу. Зачем для одной книги пагинация?

Comment: Пагинация реализована для всех.

Comment: @WilteRatenau что значит для всех? По логике должно работать `localhost/api/v1/books?start=1&limit=20` , и `localhost/api/v1/books/123` , но `localhost/api/v1/books/123/?start=1&limit=20` не должно работать

Comment: Я немного исправил описание. Вы правы это не было логичным. Однако после исправления, необходимо вызвать category_id как и напрямую в url так и без него. И при этом в обеих случаях должна работать пагинация

Comment: @WilteRatenau, тогда еще добавьте в вопрос, как вы получаете параметры start и limit